# How to read tags of SQS in AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

We are reading the subscriptions of SNS using listSubscriptionsByTopic() method which returns all the subscriptions for that topic. Subscribers includes various SQS and we would like to take different action on based on tags defined on the SQS.

Is it possible to read the tags associated with a particular SQS? We are using JavaScript SDK for AWS using Node js.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListSubscriptionsByTopic()` method returns a protocol and endpoint, which can tell you which Amazon SQS queue is subscribed to the Amazon SNS topic.

You could then use the SQS `ListQueueTags()` call to retrieve tags associated with a particular queue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer John, appreciate your answer. That will be two step process, first to find all SQS and then for each SQS, I have to make an api call to pull the associated tag. I was hoping to see a single step where I get the queue tags by listing all the subscribers for a topic.

Comment: Alas, I could not find a call that would return tags for multiple queues.